# Django run all tests at once

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am using `Django==1.7c2` and I wan't to say to `Django` find and run all tests in my project. I just created a folder with `__init__.py` which is named `tests` instead of putting all in **tests.py**.
Here is my file structure;

```
my_project/apps/my_app/
├── __init__.py
├── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_first_test.py
    ├── my_second_test.py
├── ....
├── ....
└── ....
```

and my `__init__.py` in tests file is like;

```
from my_first_test import *
from my_second_test import *
```

I thought that `Django` would recognise my `test folder` initially, but when I run just this command;

```
python manage.py test
```

There is no test case that Django find to run.

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I must run the tests for specific application in my project like;

```
python manage.py test my_project.apps.my_app.tests
```

It results;

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 1.432s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I really don't like it, because I need to run all tests in all application in my project at once instead of running them one by one. I don't know what am I missing.

**Is there a way to say Django find and run all test at once in all applications in the project?**

Thank You!

## #Edited

I have the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in my `setting.py`

Comment: Did you add your apps in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, I have them in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: version `Django==1.7c2`

Comment: I don't know about the Django-specific test suite, but default behavior in Python's standard library unittest is that you must name your test methods "test_*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ./manage.py test --pattern="*_test.py"
```

Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named “test*.py”.

**Note**

By the way you don't need import TestCases in `__init__.py` file if you are using standard test discovery (Django start using built-in test discovery since 1.6)

Comment: It seems a workaround but It worked well while I am having my test file names ending with `_test.py`.

Comment: I think it's better, then, to rename your test modules if there aren't too many